# mysql query nested query double sort

Tags: mysql, subquery

I use simple sql query like this: `$sql="SELECT name, DATE_FORMAT(date_add,'%d-%m-%Y') as mydate, payment FROM atable"`and I get 3 column table in ex:

```
name  mydate     payment
luke  10-12-2015  50
tom   13-12-2015  60
john  13-12-2015  40
tom   14-12-2015  30
eva   15-12-2015  40
john  16-12-2015  70
tom   16-12-2015  20
```

Is it possible to write sql query (I guess maybe somehow nested one) like this that first I would get a sum of payments of each group by name and then sort it DESC by sum but the final table would be like this:

```
name  mydate     payment
john  13-12-2015  40
john  16-12-2015  70
tom   13-12-2015  60
tom   14-12-2015  30
tom   16-12-2015  20
luke  10-12-2015  50
eva   15-12-2015  40
```

john is first because his sum of payments is 110, the same as tom's but he's first alphabetically, then luke and eva last. How the query would look like (if possible to do all the steps in one sql query)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13b2bc/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE atable
    (`name` varchar(4), `mydate` datetime, `payment` int)
;

INSERT INTO atable
    (`name`, `mydate`, `payment`)
VALUES
    ('luke', '2015-12-10 00:00:00', 50),
    ('tom', '2015-12-13 00:00:00', 60),
    ('john', '2015-12-13 00:00:00', 40),
    ('tom', '2015-12-14 00:00:00', 30),
    ('eva', '2015-12-15 00:00:00', 40),
    ('john', '2015-12-16 00:00:00', 70),
    ('tom', '2015-12-16 00:00:00', 20)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
      atable.name
    , atable.mydate
    , atable.payment
    , g.sum_payment
from atable
inner join (
            select name, sum(payment) as sum_payment
            from atable
            group by name
           ) g on atable.name = g.name
order by
      g.sum_payment DESC
    , atable.name
    , atable.mydate
    , atable.payment
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13b2bc/2/0)**:

```
| name |                     mydate | payment | sum_payment |
|------|----------------------------|---------|-------------|
| john | December, 13 2015 00:00:00 |      40 |         110 |
| john | December, 16 2015 00:00:00 |      70 |         110 |
|  tom | December, 13 2015 00:00:00 |      60 |         110 |
|  tom | December, 14 2015 00:00:00 |      30 |         110 |
|  tom | December, 16 2015 00:00:00 |      20 |         110 |
| luke | December, 10 2015 00:00:00 |      50 |          50 |
|  eva | December, 15 2015 00:00:00 |      40 |          40 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="SELECT name, DATE_FORMAT(date_add,'%d-%m-%Y') as mydate, payment FROM atable group by name order by payment DESC"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="SELECT name, DATE_FORMAT(date_add,'%d-%m-%Y') as mydate, sum(payment) as total FROM atable group by name order by total DESC"
```

we need to sum and group by as per your requirement.